# Libgdx - OpenGL: UI design with glScissor makes animation jerky, how can I fix it?

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm building a ListView which contains many items, and I've apply glScissor on each item
to prevent the image overflowing of its area. Everything seem to work fine.
But when I drag them quickly, all items are moving but it seem the glScissor don't fit with the image.
I think the problem may because of glScissor took integer as its parameters while the image moving at
floating precision, and I must perform a casting when using.If so, how can I fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.
Here my snippet code:

```
enableScissor((int) clippingRectangle.x,
                    (int) (clippingRectangle.y + clippingRectangle.height),
                    (int) clippingRectangle.width,
                    (int) clippingRectangle.height);
draw(this.itemBorder, this.getAbsoluteX(), this.getAbsoluteY());//draw Texture here
disableScissor();
```

where enableScissor is:

```
public void enableScissor( float clipX, float clipY, float clipWidth, float clipHeight) {
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    Gdx.gl.glScissor((int)(clipX),
                    (int) (clipY),
                    (int)(clipWidth),
                    (int)(clipHeight);
    }
```

You can see this is implemented without glScissor enabled by video:
http://youtu.be/yJlhO_ZBufE
and this is with glScissor enabled:
http://youtu.be/vGRfgYnHixA?list=UU3ndtzcT6vPfupZ4_Bm1vrQ

Comment: Are you flushing the mesh or ending the sprite batch before changing the scissor bounds for each rect?

Comment: Yeah, draw() here is actually begin(), draw(), end().

Comment: OK, I figure out the problem. It's my fault in calculate wrong clipping area. The glScissor itself is work correctly. Thanks for your concern.